# Uncaught ReferenceError: vR is not defined

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm using Google Charts api for creating some graphs.
Suddenly the graphs stopped working, and I can see only

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: vR is not defined
```

in javascript console.
I'm loading the script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if I've edited something in javascript, probably not. Could this be caused by some typing mistake? 
I'd like to ask you if you could help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found out when I compared working and not working chart. I had initialization like this

```
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart', 'bar', 'line']});
```

I removed bar and line, and now it works. Strange is, that before it worked without problem. So I replaced with this

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
```

Comment: Looks like this is actually related to the caching issues with the loader and the latest update.  There've been reports all over related to intermittent issues with undefined properties and functions.  Switching to a specific numbered version like 43 or 44 instead of 'current' has been an effective workaround for most.